# fetch values from a loop inside .then in nodejs out in allemails array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, promise

```
// importing required builtin modules
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb');

// schema for email
var emailSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    html: String,
    text: String,
    headers: {},
    subject: String,
    references: [String],
    messageId: String,
    inReplyTo: [String],
    priority: String,
    from: [],
    replyto: [String],
    to: [],
    date: Date,
    receivedDate: Date,
    attachments: [],
    read: { type: Boolean, default: 0 },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    active: { type: Boolean, default: 1 },
    labels: [String]
});

// schema for thread
var threadSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    threadedEmails: [{ type: String, ref: 'Email' }],
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

// defining models
var Email = mongoose.model('Email', emailSchema);
var Thread = mongoose.model('Thread', threadSchema);
module.exports = Email;
module.exports = Thread;

// function to return an array which contains yet anohter array of emails each representing a thread
function doCalls() {

    threads = [];

    // a promise that always resolves
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve(1);
    })

    // this returns the threads as expected
    .then(function (result) {
    return Promise.resolve(
        Thread.find({}, { threadedEmails: 1, _id: 0 }).then(
            (_threads) => { return _threads }, //resolve
            (err) => { reject(err); } //reject
        )
    )
    })

    // this does not returns the emails array as i expect
    .then(function (threads) {
    allEmails = [];
    threads.forEach(thread => {
        // Start off with a promise that always resolves
        var sequence = Promise.resolve();
        sequence = sequence.then(function (result) {
            console.log('then of first foreach');

            //query to make a database call to get all the emails whoes messageId's matchs
            query = Email.find({ messageId: { "$in": thread.threadedEmails } });
            query.exec((err, result) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                allEmails.push(result); //but this does not works because the code execution moves ahead
                console.log(result);    //this console log returns the value
            });
        })
    })
    //----------------- this is the problematic code here this array returns empty ----------------//
    console.log(allEmails);

    })
}
doCalls()
    .then(function (allEmails) {
    // console.log(allEmails);
    });
```

I have written comments where ever i feel is required in the code, even though let me explain that context of what I am trying

- I am fetching from a collection named threads all the threads which goes successfully
- after that I am trying to fetch all the emails from a collection named email using a database query the output of which i am trying to store inside an array called allEmails
- if i console.log() it in .then() just after the database call it does gives me the output,
- my question is how do I get this out ?
- I want an array which contains yet  another array each having a collection of emails(each representing a thread) from emails collection

hope I made it clear, if there is anything else I require to provide please be my guide and tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forEach block finishes before any of the async operations inside it return. Thus , your allEmails array will still be empty when you console.log it.

What you need to do is build an array of promises that resolve with the "result" and then feed this array into Promise.all(arrayOfPromises) which will resolve when all your promises are resolved.

Promise.all is kind enough to resolve with the array of results for you. 
Your last then would look something like:

```
.then(function (threads) {
  const promiseArray = [];
  threads.forEach(thread => promiseArray.push(
      Promise.resolve(Email.find({ messageId: { "$in": thread.threadedEmails } }))
    )
  );
  return Promise.all(promiseArray);
}
```

That being said, for what you're trying to achieve, Model.aggregate() would be a much more elegant solution.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the reply it worked for me, except one single correction, Promise.resolve is a method call which should not be preceded with "new" keyword

Comment: @PreetsinghPanesar you should mark the answer as correct if it worked for you, thanks !